# Coloring a margin on Avalonedit

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, margin, avalonedit

I have added a margin (For adding breakpoints) to the left side of my TextEditor in the following manner:

```
public partial class LogicSimViewCodeWPFCtrl : UserControl
    {

private class BreakPointMargin : AbstractMargin
    {
        private const int margin = 20;
        protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
        {
            return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            return new Size(margin, 0);
        }
    }
}

    private void LogicCodeInit()
    {
        try
        {
            TxtEditCodeViewer.TextArea.LeftMargins.Insert(0, new BreakPointMargin());
            ...
```

The margin is added successfully but now I'd like to color the background of the margin. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20190716171503/http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/16047.aspx

You would have to override `OnRender`:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Size renderSize = this.RenderSize;
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(SystemColors.ControlBrush, null,
                                     new Rect(0, 0, renderSize.Width, renderSize.Height));
```

Also, you aren't required to derived from `AbstractMargin` - you can use any WPF control you want. `AbstractMargin` just provides the `TextView` and `Document` properties and keeps them up to date. If you don't need those or can implement them yourself, you can just use another base class.